# Why does TPanel's color property display the wrong color when using a hex color value?

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 2010 and if I create a new VCL application, drop a TPanel on the form and set its "color" property to "clInactiveCaptionText" it shows the correct color.

**Correct color:**

[image]

However, if I enter the hex value for this color ($00434E54 --- R 67,G 78,B 84) it shows up incorrectly. I should note that the result is the same whether I enable runtime themes or not.

**Wrong color:**

[image]

Any idea on why it won't correctly show this color when specifying its hex value?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

RGB color values are actually specified as BGR.

So if you want:

- red you need to specify $000000FF
- green you need to specify $0000FF00
- blue you need to specify $00FF0000

Comment: Thank you! Following your instructions I changed the color to $00544E43 and it works like it should.

Answer (score 17):

As others have indicated, the RGB values are stored internally as **BGR** (i.e. `TColor` value, or what Windows calls a `COLORREF`), that's why when you specify a custom color code you obtain a different color.

To maintain your sanity when specifying colors in RGB form you can use the **RGB()** function from  the Windows unit; this accepts parameters in the "natural"/intuitive RGB order (as byte values) and yields an appropriate `TColor` / `COLORREF` value:

```
  MyPanel.Color := RGB(67, 78, 84);
```

or if hex is easier:

```
  MyPanel.Color := RGB($43, $4E, $54);
```

Comment: +1 for the sanity remark. I can remember going crazy when I first encountered this.

Answer (score 8):

This is because you are setting a [`TColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TColor) value in a RGB format you must use BGR instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Tcolor is RGBA color format and also `$FF000000` is the alpha channel so:

- To get red chanel you can get $000000FF
- To get green chanel you can get $0000FF00
- To get bluechanel you can get $00FF0000
- To get alpha chanel chanel you can get $FF000000

And easily you can convert the tcolor value to rgb by :

```
IntToHex(ColorPanel1.Color,1)
```

this also work in cross platform FMX delphi apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function HexToColor(sColor : string) : TColor;
begin
   Result :=
     RGB(
       StrToInt('$'+Copy(sColor, 1, 2)),
       StrToInt('$'+Copy(sColor, 3, 2)),
       StrToInt('$'+Copy(sColor, 5, 2))
     ) ;
end;
```

With this simple function you can make easier:

```
Panel1.Color := HexToColor ('16a086');
```